# How do I change the language of the German version of Fallout 3 to English?

Tags: fallout-3

I have Fallout 3 GOTY on Steam and it's in German. Low-violence version doesn't bother me, but the fact that I can't change the game's language to English.

I want to play the game as it was intended to be and not with the poor German replacements of word jokes, etc. So does anybody know how to change the language to English? This could be through an English language patch or mod, or the English game files.

**EDIT: There is no option in Steam to change the language.**

**EDIT 2: I have already tried all "legitimate" options, the only possible way would be to replace game files or apply a language patch**

**EDIT 3: Steam provides me only with the german low-violence gamefiles.**

Comment: Are you able to change the language in the options? You can also use a translator to help you out.

Comment: Have you tried changing Steam  language ? Not just for the game, for the whole client. This usually works.

You can also look [here](http://www.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_I_change_the_language_in_my_Fallout_New_Vegas_from_Russian_to_English), I don't know if it works though.

Comment: My steam client and all other games are of course in english

Comment: Sorry, Paedow.  We're not very good at providing links to specific resource requests; answers aren't very useful to anyone but the asker, and they tend to be link-only answers, which is anathema to SE.

Comment: There seems to be no solution. Moreover, according to [this thread](http://www.rpgcodex.net/forums/index.php?threads/new-vegas-german-version-english-language-files-possible.68522/), it is a recurring issue for Bethesda games.

Comment: I've edited your question to ask for any solution, and not for "links to specific resource requests" (as per a previous comment), to avoid close votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the [language files here](http://schote.biz/sprachdateien-deutschpatches/13-fallout-3-game-of-the-year/1300-englische-texte-untertitel-menus-stimmen-sprachausgabe.html). A guide on how to apply these files is contained in the download.

Comment: This is a link-only answer.  You must summarize the instructions on how to use them, at least.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of to change languages in fallout 3 would be a language MOD. It is worth mentioning that I was able to pick up fallout 3 GOTY edition here in Australia for a dollar. It saved to my games for windows live account, not steam, but I can re-download the game from the GFWL client despite originally purchasing a disc copy.

If you are able to get a deal like mine, it might be worth simply buying a English CD key and enjoying the native English version with all its violent splendour.

Comment: I'd like to keep my games in steam with the overlay and screenshots and the steam community stuff (i love achievements)

Comment: Just see if you can get a US steam key..

Comment: Not true at all. It took a five second text file change to play the US version of left for dead 2, on its release to australia, and no IP manipulation what so ever. It depends on the game.

Comment: Let me be more precise: Steam has a regional lock on games. It uses the IP **but does not use the IP to 100% confirm the content**. I have used this workaround to play "regional locked games" for years. Everything you explain is exactly how the standard version would work. Change a few numbers in its "steam pointer" and it unlocks, and plays the "technically illegal" un-rated version. If this is not the case for Fallout, it would not be specifically due to Steam, as I find it hard to believe steam would enable this "more secure" feature for some games, and not others.