# Fallout 3 - GOTY get CD key from steam for windows live / change lanugage

Tags: steam, fallout-3, games-for-windows-live

I have Fallout3-GOTY (steam-app #22370) and wish to change the game's language from german to english.
My steam-account is configured in english and steam correctly downloads the game in english.
When I launch F3, the "Pre-loader" (Settings, Data-files, etc.) is in english, but the game itself is in german. (I already wiped it, restarted steam and redownloaded)
From what I gathered through googling is, that I need to change the language in GFWL.
Therefore I open the GFWL-overlay and browse through it all, but cannot find anything.
Some options are blocked though by the fact, that I am not "connected to LIVE" and to do that I need a key, to connect the game to my LIVE-account.

Now here's the problem:
Steam does not provide me with a key, but LIVE won't go on without it.
Is there a way to otherwise change the in-game language or do I need that key?
If so: How can I get it?

EDIT:
[How do I change the language of the German version of Fallout 3 to English?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/225412/how-do-i-change-the-language-of-the-german-version-of-fallout-3-to-english)
same question, also no solution.
From what I am getting all over the web, it seems that this is intentionally impossible.
Yay, great.

Comment: You can mod the game so that it prevents the GFWL .dll file from executing, basically preventing the game using GFWL - check this mod: http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout3/mods/1086/

Comment: @imulsion thanks, but that is not what I am looking for. I can play the game without being connected to LIVE, but I need to find a way to change the language. Just excluding LIVE sadly does not do that.

Comment: You say that "some options are blocked because I'm not connected to my live account". Surely that means if you disable GFWL you'll be able to change the language?

Comment: @imulsion those options are inside the GFWL-overlay, not the game's option. So completely excluding GFWL will probably not help me here.

Also I am slowly getting to the conclusion that there intentionally is no way of doing this because the german version is not only in german, but also cut. Why that shall prevent me from at least getting a proper sound, shall remain known only be bethesda -_-

Comment: Did you use the CD key that Steam provides? In Steam Library, right-click the game, and select view CD key.

Comment: @Tkdestroyer2 steam does not provide one in this case, otherwise I would have done that.

Comment: if the other question has not got the response you would like, define how your question is different. Alternatively, you could post on the previous question (bringing it to the top, just like a new question), or place a bounty on it, to attract better answers.

Comment: I can confirm that if you buy the game through GFWL, or as a physical copy that gives you a GFWL key, rather, it will not transfer over to Steam.

Comment: @Timelord64 too bad I bought it through steam ._.

Comment: You have the censored version? Are you POSITIVE you have the exact version linked to from appID 22370? That appears to be an uncensored version, which would have a separate ID number. If your version DOES use a different ID, there may be a fairly easy solution. We did it back when L4D2 was released and Australia's version got censored.

Comment: I answered the question you linked. I am German too and I provided the definitive answer. I can play Fallout in English just fine.

Comment: are you playing the **german censored** version, which is different to the version this user appears to be asking about?

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness Same as the OP of the other question sadly: no language tab there in steam. How did you purchase the game?

Comment: @Timelord64 yep, I got the german censored Version. There is probably a redirect for me under that appID.

Comment: bummer. My solution involves re-routing using the appID. If they share the same ID, it wont work. What confuses me is that Left 4 Dead 2 did not have as big of a change, due to censorship. But the censored version **did** have a differant appID, and that was how we got around it.

Comment: @Mark On GamersGate.com as a Key and activated it without VPN.